# enter in mysql link for url by php using form html

Tags: php, html

mywebsite.com/edit.php?id=95422&name=myname&websit=**http**://stackoverflow.com/&edit=Save+Edit

like this photo
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8WM95baqRBib3kxd3RKa0lYeVE/view?usp=sharing

in video I enter link for web sit when press save get me error in page 404

because **http** in texterea in video I use form get in html to get field and but it in mysql

how can i let get the link without http or any something ways to do it

Comment: `str_replace('http', '', $text);`

Comment: i try it but you can not use str_replace after get because page in error
i need use way to use after press submit button :\

Comment: what is the error, why there is an 404 error,

Comment: hhhhh :D
damn it your question is very helpful i figure it out
I solved the problem ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can remove http:// from video link when submit page via javascript and when you save in database then you can add http:// again.

Comment: i know but what if there 100 people enter and someone forget to remove it let them see error